# File Chooser on facebook in webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a webview that loads a webpage that contains the Facebook comments plugin. The **"Attach image"** option is enabled in comments, but does not work in the webview. Is it possible to perform this action by choosing the image in the gallery and posting within the webview?

**I added this permission in Manifest:**

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">`

This is my code **Site.class**:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;


public class Site extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = Site.class.getSimpleName();


    protected WebView mainWebView;
    private Context mContext;
    private WebView mWebviewPop;
    private FrameLayout mContainer;

    private String url= "http://example.com";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_site);



        mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mContext = this.getApplicationContext();


        // if you want to make sure that we need to log in facebook again ...
//        clearCookies(this);

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);


        mainWebView = getWebView(mContext);

        // handle the opening of facebook
        mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomChromeClient());

        mainWebView.loadUrl(url);

        mContainer.addView(mainWebView);


    }


    /**
     * get webview with all necessary properties to support facebook login
     */
    WebView getWebView(Context context) {
        WebView wv = new WebView(context);
        wv.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        wv.clearCache(true);

        // Settings for the webview
        if (isOnline()) {
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(wv, true);
        }
        } else {
            /* deve cair aqui caso não haja internet */
            Intent i = new Intent(Blog.this, Error.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }


        return wv;
    }
    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }


    private class MyCustomChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                      boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            mWebviewPop = getWebView(mContext);
            mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
                    Log.d(TAG, "host=" + host);
                    if (host.contains("facebook.com")) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }

                    // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
                    // another Activity that handles URLs
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            mWebviewPop.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomChromeClient());

            mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);

            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
            // facebook login finishes, close the facebook window and return to the main one
            Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");

            mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
            mWebviewPop = null;

        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void clearCookies(Context context) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Using clearCookies code for API >=" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
            CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
            CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Using clearCookies code for API <" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
            CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
            cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
            cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
            cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
            cookieSyncMngr.sync();
        }
    }
}
```